# Add icon to ion-option in ion-select

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

is it possible to add icon to ion-option in ion-select? 
something like

```
<ion-select  name="type">
        <ion-option value="bar"><ion-icon name="stats"></ion-icon>Bar</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="pie"><ion-icon name="pie"></ion-icon>Pie</ion-option>
      </ion-select>
```

Comment: I don't know how to solve it either. Help would be appreciated :)

Comment: I'm having the same issue :(

Answer (score 2):

[image]

This worked for me.

using CSS to modify the inner span in the button tag of each option, removing radius and assigning a brackground image

the options keep the same order, and that is why the attribute selector worked for me

```
.alert-radio-icon{
    border-radius: 0 !important;
    border: none !important;
    height: 40px !important;
    width: 40px !important;
    background-size: 40px 40px !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat ;
}

    [id^="alert-input-"][id$="-0"] .alert-radio-icon{
        background-image: url("../assets/images/menu/flag_ni.png") !important;
    }
     [id^="alert-input-"][id$="-1"] .alert-radio-icon{
        background-image: url("../assets/images/menu/flag_gt.png") !important;
    }
    .alert-radio-inner{
        background-color: transparent !important;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

hey you  can try this ...

this worked for me ..
Check out this site :
https://www.alt-codes.net/star_alt_code.php

i used this code : ✰

so my code looks like this :

```
<ion-item>
            <ion-label>Member's Overall Rating</ion-label>
            <ion-select [(ngModel)]="newreport.memberstatus">
            <ion-option value="&#10032;">&#10032;</ion-option>
            <ion-option value="&#10032;&#10032;">&#10032;&#10032;</ion-option>
            <ion-option value="&#10032;&#10032;&#10032;">&#10032;&#10032;&#10032;</ion-option>
            <ion-option value="&#10032;&#10032;&#10032;&#10032;">&#10032;&#10032;&#10032;&#10032;</ion-option>
            <ion-option value="&#10032;&#10032;&#10032;&#10032;&#10032;">&#10032;&#10032;&#10032;&#10032;&#10032;</ion-option>
            </ion-select>
            </ion-item>
```

the result is this (screenshot on my phone cause im  testing on my phone) :

[screenshot of what the results would be like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syBA3.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

**IonIcons in IonSelect:**

[image: IonIcon in IonSelect]

The ion-select-option only returns strings however, all the Ion-Select technically does is show an interface that looks like a dropdown.

In short, what you can do, is, in this example, create a popover component that appears instead, of the normal dropdown by putting the dropdown in a clickable ion-item, disabling the dropdown, making it look enabled (for UX), clicking the dropdown when ion-item is clicked and then using that reference to open a popover component at that location.

So, there's some considerations I made when doing this:

1. I didn't want to recreate the dropdown box and icon, I only wanted to change what it displayed
2. I also wanted the icon to be clickable

Solution I ended up with (note this was also using ReactiveForms):

**menu-options.interface.ts**

```
export interface MenuOptions {
  key: string;
  fn: () => {};
}
```

MenuOptions will hold the value to display and the function to run when the button is pressed

**main.component.ts**

```
constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef){}

menuOptions: MenuOptions[] = [
    {
      key: "Text",
      fn: () =>
        this._showAlert("Select this option if you want to type in values"),
    },
    {
      key: "List",
      fn: () =>
        this._showAlert(
          "Select this option if you want to use a pre-defined list of values"
        ),
    },
    {
      key: "Textbox",
      fn: () =>
        this._showAlert(
          "Select this option if you want an area to type a block of text"
        ),
    },
];

// Find location of where popover is to appear and click the element
// which will then trigger the (click) event
onSelectionClick(event: any) {
    let element: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('popoverLoc') as HTMLElement;
    element.click();
}


async openPopover(event: any) {
    const popover = await this.popover.create({
      component: SelectionTypePopoverComponent,
      componentProps: {
        menuOptions: this.menuOptions
      },
      event,
      translucent: true,
    });

    await popover.present();

    const {data} = await popover.onWillDismiss();

    // Get return from popover and set selection value
    this.itemFeatureForm.get('selectionType').setValue(data['selectionType']);

        // If you hardcode the menu options directly in the popover component and pass them back
        // you will need to trigger change detection manually and set array to have 1 value
        // otherwise your dropdown wont appear properly
        // menuOptions: MenuOptions[] =  [{ key: '', fn: () => '' }] 
        //this.cd.detectChanges();
    }
```

**main.component.html**

```
      <ion-item button (click)="onSelectionClick($event)" detail="false">
        <ion-label class="enableItem">Selection Type</ion-label>
        <ion-select
          formControlName="selectionType"
          class="enableItem"
          id="popoverLoc"
          (click)="openPopover($event)"
        >
          <ion-select-option
            *ngFor="let option of menuOptions"
            [value]="option.key"
            >{{ option.key }}</ion-select-option
          >
        </ion-select>
      </ion-item>
```

1. Wrap Ion-Label/Ion-Select in a clickable Ion-Item.  This is going to be what registers the first click.
2. Make sure your ion-select is disabled: `selectionType: new FormControl({value: '', disabled: true}),`
3. enableItem class to make your Ion-Select look enabled: `.enableItem {opacity: 1 !important;}`
4. Set id to mark location of ion-select

**popover.component.html**

```
<ion-list>
  <div *ngFor="let option of menuOptions; let i = index">
    <ion-grid class="ion-no-padding">
      <ion-row class="ion-no-padding">
        <ion-col class="ion-no-padding">
          <ion-item button detail="false" (click)="onSelection(i)">
            <ion-label>{{ option.key }}</ion-label>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col class="ion-no-padding" size="2">
          <ion-item class="ion-no-padding">
            <ion-button class="ion-no-padding" fill="clear" (click)="onInfo(i)">
              <ion-icon
                name="information-circle-outline"
                slot="icon-only"
              ></ion-icon>
            </ion-button>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
  </div>
</ion-list>
```

Make sure to set the size of the icon column

**popover.component.ts**

```
onSelection(index: number) {
    this.popoverCtrl.dismiss({
      selectionType: this.menuOptions[index].key,
    });
}

onInfo(index: number) {
    this.menuOptions[index].fn();
}
```

I've not done testing on physical devices yet but when I do, if this doesn't work, I will update but at the moment, with this pattern I can make whatever I want to appear in a dropdown and still using ionic templating...great power, responsibility and all that.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing I could come up with is using unicode characters as the ion-option content. Like this one:

Answer (score 0):

This isn't supported by Ionic. 
[See comment from Kensodeman on this issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/12756)

So I guess it's only possible with some kind of workaround as suggested by Luis.

Answer (score 0):

I found one of the possible quick solutions

```html
<ion-select interface="popover" [interfaceOptions]="{ cssClass: 'myClass' }">
 <ion-select-option> value </ion-select-option>
 <ion-select-option> value </ion-select-option>
</ion-select>
```

global.css

```css
.myClass{
    ion-item:nth-child(1) .sc-ion-select-popover-md{
        background: url("/my-icon");
        background-size: 20px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        padding: 0px 27px;
    }
    ion-item:nth-child(2) .sc-ion-select-popover-md{
        background: url("/my-icon");
        background-size: 20px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        padding: 0px 27px;
    }
}
```

replace css class depending on interface